# Dictionary not passing to the template django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to read a cookie and pass the data into the template but it returns a string `/cart` on the template.

**view.py**

```
def cart(request):
    # exception no cookie named 'cart'
    try:
        cart = json.loads(request.COOKIES['cart'])
    except:
        cart = {}

    context = {
        'data': [],
        'cart': cart,
    }

    for item in cart:
        product_detail = ProductImage.objects.select_related(
                            'product'
                         ).filter(product=item[0], place='Main Product Image')
        
        context['data'].append(product_detail)

    return render(request, 'store/cart.html', context)
```

I've checked whether the `cart` variable contains data and it does contain a dictionary. Following is the `context` variable,

```
 {'data': [<QuerySet [<ProductImage: Product 1-22>]>], 'cart': {'1': {'unit_price': '980.00', 'quantity': 3}}}
```

when I tried to print the cart in the template using `{{ cart }}` it returns `/cart` but the `data` key contains all the data and can be displayed in the template.

**template**

```
 {{ cart }} <!-- for testing -->

{% for item in data %}
    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}
      <div class="row border-bottom pb-3 pt-1 cart-item">
    {% else %}
      <div class="row border-bottom pb-3 pt-1 cart-item" style="background-color: #F8F8F8">
    {% endif %}
        <div class="col-sm-1 d-md-flex justify-content-center align-items-center remove-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn bg-transparent"
                  data-action="delete" data-product="{{ item.0.product.id }}_{{ item.0.product.get_sale_price|floatformat:2 }}">
            <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="{{ item.0.image.url }}" alt="" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm">
          <a href="product/{{ item.0.product.id }}" class="cart-product-link">
            <h5> {{ item.0.product.name }}</h5>
            <p class="module fades">
              {{ item.0.product.desc }}
            </p>
          </a>
        </div>

        <!-- quantity -->
        <div class="col col-sm input-group my-auto text-center">
          <div class="quantity ml-5">
            <input type="number" class="update-quantity" data-action="q_add" min="1" max="20" step="1"
                   value="{{ cart|get_quantity:item.0.product.id }}" style="width: 50px"
              data-product="{{ item.0.product.id }}_{{ item.0.product.get_sale_price|floatformat:2 }}">
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- cost -->
        <div class="col col-sm mt-lg-5  text-center cost-container">

            <span class="cost">{{ cart|get_cost:item.0.product.id }}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

So hoping to know what's going on here thanks in advance.

**Update(wierd scenario)**

The same thing happened again in a different file and I tried to do the solution [bellow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66456172/8388057) mentioned. Unfortunately, it didn't work. After hours of trying, I decided to rename the key of the dict `{'cart': cart,...}` to `{'crt':cart}` and it worked.

Comment: Can you update the question with the snippet of template?

Comment: @ShivendraPratapKushwaha done... {{ cart }} is for just debugging

Comment: can you render like 'return render(request, 'store/cart.html', {'context' : context})' and in template fetch like {{context.cart}}... check if this works...

Comment: That works :) can retrieve the dict but why? and how? can you explain that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass a context dict variable in the template. All you need to do is :

```
return render(request, 'store/cart.html', {'context' : context})
```

By this we are passing the context to html template. And the you can retrieve the context data by :

```
{{context.cart}}
```